# Expression engine: list categories of results, preventing category name duplication

Tags: duplicates, expressionengine, categories

I'm trying to achieve something like this

**Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3| Category 4 | <strike>Category 5</strike> | <strike>Category 6</strike>

Product 1 (in category 1)

Product 2 (in categories 1 and 2)

Product 3 (in categories 1 and 3

Product 4 (In category 4)

Product 5 (In category 5)**

Basically, it's a results page, with the categories the products have been assigned to as a menu.

This is what I'm obtaining with the above product data

**Category 1 | Category 1 | Category 1 |  Category 2 | Category 3 | Category 4 | Category 5

Product 1 (in category 1)

Product 2 (in categories 1 and 2)

Product 3 (in categories 1 and 3

Product 4 (In category 4)

Product 5 (In category 5)**

I've been using this Expression engine tag (I've used GW code categories extension, but it should be easily done with standard Expression engine tag)

```
exp:gwcode_categories channel="products" group_id="1" output_depth="2" entry_id="{entry_id}" entry_count="yes"}
```

How do I exclude duplicate entries from the category listing?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do the best way to do this would be to have one channel entries tag and pass in the category list. You could use dynamic parameters

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic_parameters="category" dynamic="no" }
```

Or pass them in through in through in through a embed variable (1&3&6, etc).

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{embed:catid} dynamic="no" }
```

If it is a long product list and you need pagination it may be easiest to go with something like [dynamo](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dynamo).